# How to set up a multibranch or GitHub organization build to run just at night

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

With multibranch or GitHub organization jobs you can configure `Scan Repository Triggers`. But the bad thing is that you can just tell it to scan each x minutes. There is no means of just scanning at specific times. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can define CRON triggers in a Jenkinsfile

```
properties(
    [
        pipelineTriggers([cron('0 * * * *')]),
    ]
)
```

[Here's an example](https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8-snapshot-cleanup/blob/4d3b9572d71a3bc29df9e2214bb44c1684980878/Jenkinsfile#L4-L8)

Comment: Multibranch or GitHub organization jobs come before the processing of the jenkinsfile so this doesn't apply unfortunately (as far as I know). The specific branches are then assigned a dedicated job INSIDE which then checks out the pipeline script. So this will just apply to the nested job, not to the multibranch/organization job that scans the repository.

Comment: That Jenkinsfile is used in a multi branch job as we use the GitHub Organisation plugin so it will work.  The first time the job is run it then configures the job with the CRON trigger.

Comment: OK so still I need to configure the Organization to to poll e.g. every 10 minutes. Which means the nested jobs are executed directly after the scan. That is not what I want. Or please correct me if I missed a point here...